# (sql) how to connent and get something between 2 table

Tags: mysql, sql

the question is that

TableA

```
(`manufacturerID`, `company_name`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `post_code`, `area_code`, `phone_number`)

('AA04', 'Ken', '6000 16th Ave N', 'San Diego', 'CA', '92101', '213', '981-8745'),

('AA05', 'Lenar', '1230 9th Ave N', 'Baltimore', 'MD', '21202', '301', '321-0987');
```

TableB

```
(`productID`, `product_name`, `price`, `sale_price`, `in_stock`, `on_order`, `categoryID`, `manufacturerID`) 

('CT200', 'China Puppy', 15, 13.5, 20, 40, 4, 'AA04'),

('CT201', 'Wooden Puppy', 18, 14.5, 15, 25, 4, 'AA04'),

('CT202', 'Tanjore Doll', 17, 13.5, 20, 40, 2, 'AA01'),
```

How many toy products are manufactured by Ken?

it is my answer

```
SELECT COUNT( `manufacturerID` ) 
FROM `toyproducts` 
WHERE `manufacturerID` = 'AA04'
```

but what is the correct answer?

Comment: I'm expecting to see a `JOIN` for the answer to this question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, which DBMS are you using?

Comment: phpmyadmin i got the answer already thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use natural join to connect your tables. As the common column on which we can connect the two tables have same name we can use natural join. Generally inner join with a join condition works.

```
select count(manufacturerID) FROM TableA NATURAL JOIN TableB where company_name='Ken'
```

Although inner join are more readable than natural joins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `INNER JOIN` to get all the products where `company_name` is `Ken`:

```
SELECT COUNT( p.manufacturerID )
FROM TableA m JOIN toyproducts p
ON m.manufacturerID = p.manufacturerID
WHERE m.company_name = 'Ken'
```

Comment: thanks a lot 
but what is the meaning of m , p in that sql code
new to SQL sorry about asking a stupid question

Comment: @ChakyinChow It is a range variable i.e. ranges over the set of tuples in some relation (or the set of rows in some table, in SQL terms).

Comment: @ChakyinChow **In very simple English**, I would say its a nick name for the table so I don't have to write the complete table name. 
**Technically** it is in scope alias of the table.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways of writing this in SQL e.g. here's one:

```
SELECT COUNT( manufacturerID ) AS tally
  FROM toyproducts
 WHERE manufacturerID IN ( SELECT manufacturerID
                             FROM TableA 
                            WHERE company_name = 'Ken' );
```